# How to spellcheck a range of cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I get a type mismatch error on `textToCheck = Range("A:C")`.

It works if I do one cell. e.g. `Range(A1)`.

How can I

1. loop through each cell (A:C)?
2. only show msgbox on not correctly spelled values?

```vb
Sub SpellCheckSheet()
    Dim correctlySpelled As Boolean, textToCheck As String
    Call unprotect_sheet
    
    textToCheck = Range("A:C")
    correctlySpelled = Application.CheckSpelling(textToCheck)
    
    If Not correctlySpelled Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect Spelling of: " & textToCheck
    Else
        MsgBox "Correct Spelling of: " & textToCheck
    End If
          
    Call protect_sheet
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim cell As Range`, `For Each cell In Intersect(Range("A:C"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at each that has a value in columns A through C.  Try this:

```
 Sub SpellCheckSheet()
     Dim correctlySpelled As Boolean, textToCheck As String
     Dim cell As Range
     
     Call unprotect_sheet
     
     For Each cell In Intersect(Range("A:C"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
         textToCheck = cell.Value
         correctlySpelled = Application.CheckSpelling(textToCheck)
    
         If Not correctlySpelled Then
             MsgBox "Incorrect Spelling of: " & textToCheck
         End If
     Next
     
     Call protect_sheet

 End Sub
```